# Can someone explain what this piece of code is doing?

Tags: powershell

This is code I found that splits an array into odd or even results.

```
$f=0; $array | % { if($f = !$f) { $_ } }
```

The part I don't understand is the `if` statement. Specifically `$f=!$f`.

The way I'm reading it is `if(0 = not 0)`. The result should always be true since it's using `=` and not `-eq`. I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing, but I can't find any info on it.

If anyone has any good resources to read that goes further into this type of logic I'd also love to read more on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's showing every odd array element.  $f goes back and forth from $true to $false.  The value of the assignment is what's on the left side.  I would start with $f = $false, to make it a little more clear.

```
!0
True

!$true
False

$array = 1..10
$f=0; $array | % { if($f = !$f) { $_ } }
1
3
5
7
9
```

Comment: I think you meant "it's showing every even element of the array". Might be confusing because you're slicing from `1` instead of `0`.

Comment: This makes complete sense now. For some reason, my brain was correlating the value of `$f` with the index value of the array. Your explanation was perfect in helping me understand the purpose of `$f`.

Answer (score 3):

The `=` in the `if()` is an ***assignment***, not a ***comparison*** (which would use `-eq`, as you noted). So, each pass through the `ForEach-Object` loop toggles the value of `$f` between `$false` and `$true`, and emits the passed value from the array when it’s `$true`. As written, it gives you the values in the even-numbered positions in the array (zero-origin). If you start with `$f=1`, it will give the values in the odd-numbered positions.